# Can we disable a route in python flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a situation like this,

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    data = getdata
    return render_template("test.html", data=data)

@app.route("/test2")
def test2():
    data = getdatainfo
    return render_template("test2.html", data=data)
```

test route returns data like this:

```
data = [{ id:1, name:'a'}, {id:2, name:'b'}]
```

if the test route data length is equal to 2 I have to disable the route  "test2" route how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using `session`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, session
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY']= os.urandom(24)

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    data = getdata
    session['data'] = len(data)
    return render_template("test.html", data=data)


@app.route("/test2")
def test2():
    if 'data' in session and session['data'] != 2:
        data = getdatainfo
        return render_template("test2.html", data=data)
    else:
        return Response('Data Length equals 2')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```